# PROC SQL "SELECT INTO" does not create macro variable

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I've run into an issue creating macro variables using `proc sql select into :` logic. The code seems to be pretty straightforward, but I should note that the macro that is causing problems is called from several other macros.

Here is the snippet that is causing issues.

```
%do year_num=1 %to 5;
    %if &year_num=1 %then %let min_date = %eval(&max2.-17);
    %else %let min_date = %eval(&min_date.-12);

    data tmp;
    set bf(firstobs=&min_date obs=%eval(11+&min_date));
    run;

    data tmp2;
    set bf(firstobs=%eval(5+&min_date) obs=%eval(7+&min_date));
    run;

    proc sql noprint;
    select sum(EP), sum(ExpectedLoss)
      into :totep, :totexpt
    from tmp;

    select sum(EP), sum(ExpectedLoss)
      into :partep, :partexpt
    from tmp2;
    quit;

    %put _LOCAL_;

    *Other code...;

%end;
```

For some reason, the variables `totep`, `totexpt`, `partep` and `pqrtexpt` are not getting created and I can't find any useful information in the log that may shed light on the situation.

Here is part of the log, including the output from `_LOCAL_`.

```
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable YEAR_NUM resolves to 1
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable MAX2 resolves to 96
MPRINT(BFMETHOD):   data tmp;
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable MIN_DATE resolves to 79
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable MIN_DATE resolves to 79
MPRINT(BFMETHOD):   set bf(firstobs=79 obs=90);
MPRINT(BFMETHOD):   run;
MPRINT(BFMETHOD):   data tmp2;
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable MIN_DATE resolves to 79
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable MIN_DATE resolves to 79
MPRINT(BFMETHOD):   set bf(firstobs=84 obs=86);
MPRINT(BFMETHOD):   run;
MPRINT(BFMETHOD):   proc sql noprint;
MPRINT(BFMETHOD):   select sum(EP), sum(ExpectedLoss) into :totep, :totexpt from tmp;
MPRINT(BFMETHOD):   select sum(EP), sum(ExpectedLoss) into :partep, :partexpt from tmp2;
MPRINT(BFMETHOD):   quit;
BFMETHOD I 12
BFMETHOD DSET all
BFMETHOD SEAS_MIN 0.6
BFMETHOD YEAR_NUM 1
BFMETHOD SEAS_MAX 1.66666666666666
BFMETHOD MIN_DATE 79

data tmp;     set bf(firstobs=79 obs=90);     run;

NOTE: There were 12 observations read from the data set WORK.BF.
NOTE: The data set WORK.TMP has 12 observations and 35 variables.
NOTE: Compressing data set WORK.TMP increased size by 100.00 percent.
      Compressed is 2 pages; un-compressed would require 1 pages.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds

109       +    data tmp2;     set bf(firstobs=84 obs=86);     run;

NOTE: There were 3 observations read from the data set WORK.BF.
NOTE: The data set WORK.TMP2 has 3 observations and 35 variables.
NOTE: Compressing data set WORK.TMP2 increased size by 100.00 percent.
      Compressed is 2 pages; un-compressed would require 1 pages.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds


109       +                                                             proc sql noprint;
109       +                                                                                   select sum(EP), sum(ExpectedLoss)       into :totep, :totexpt     from tmp;
109       +
     select sum(EP), sum(ExpectedLoss)       into :partep, :partexpt     from tmp2;
109       +
     quit;
NOTE: PROCEDURE SQL used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.00 seconds
```

If I remove `noprint` from the `proc sql` statement then the correct values are output so I'm not sure what's going on. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: does `%put TOTEXP: &totexp;` after the `quit;` output anything?

Comment: @DomPazz No, I just get the same waning symbolic reference not resolved.

Comment: If the macro variables were declared or extant in a containing scope and are trying to be logged within an invoked macro the `%put _local%` will not log them because they are not local to the invoked scope.  Also, try adding undocumented _tree and _method options to see more detail in the log `proc sql noprint _tree _method;`  `NOPRINT` should *not* affect `INTO`.

Comment: What's the timing here?  Are you using CALL EXECUTE to run this, for example?  I think that's almost certainly related.

Comment: it is like the `PROC SQL` statements are sitting in the buffer and not being run.  Try putting `data _null_; run;` just after the `quit;` statement but before the `%put `.

Comment: @Joe Yes, this is done using CALL EXECUTE

Comment: @Richard and Dom - the way I could tell what the issue was here is that the %put _did_ do something, it just didn't do it at the right time.  You can see it output the local macro variables in the log just a ways up from the rest of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is almost certainly related to execution timing.  Particularly when using `call execute`, you can easily run into problems with timing where the macro variable is resolved by the SAS processor earlier than it's given a useful value.

Here's a simplified example.  I specifically make a dataset so you can see when that happens (it's not a necessary step nor does it affect the example, it just makes a useful log entry).

Notice how when the macro runs on its own, everything works how you'd expect; but when it's run with `call execute` the `%put` executes *before* the macro actually executes.

The third example uses `%nrstr` to force SAS to not try to resolve the macro before actually running it - which causes it to be submitted properly.

Effectively, the first `call execute` version has SAS process the macro text then submit it to sas.exe - which you do not really want.  Adding `%nrstr` fixes that.

```
%macro do_something();
    %local mlist;
    data class_m;
      set sashelp.class;
      where sex='M';
    run;

    proc sql;
      select name into :mlist separated by ' '
      from class_m;
    quit;

    %put &=mlist;
%mend do_something;

%put Macro run on its own;
%do_something;


%put Macro run via call execute;
options mprint symbolgen;
data _null_;
  set sashelp.class;
  if _n_=1 then call execute('%do_something()');
  stop;
run;

%put Macro run with nrstr and call execute;
data _null_;
  set sashelp.class;
  if _n_=1 then call execute('%nrstr(%do_something())');
  stop;
run;
```

Comment: This is perfect, I never would have thought to add `%nrstr`.